# Like button and confirm

Tags: facebook-like, confirmation

I've read all topics about this issue, but nothing help me.

I've added "Like" buttons on my http://igor-mironchik.narod.ru/projects.html page. But when I press the "Like" button I always see the "Confirm" link and sometimes after confirmation nothing happens. I mean that button disappears and after refreshing the page I see previous number of likes.

What am I doing wrong? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have og:article in your header for **multiple like** in **one page** :( try to remove og:article or ..try to add the like button in iframe

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Figor-mironchik.narod.ru%2Fprojects%2Fqtarg.html&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=120&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21&amp;appId=YOUR_APP_ID" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:120px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: I don't think so. Look at the [link](http://igor-mironchik.narod.ru/projects/qtarg.html). There is only one "like" button, but the behavior the same. And what the difference between what I add button with iframe or div?! Here is something else.